# Add values in a row, substituing 0 for NULL

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID | VALUE A | VALUE B
----------------------
1  | 20      | NULL   
2  | NULL    | 100    
3  | NULL    | NULL   
4  | 100     | 50
```

I want to run a query (Sqlite) that returns the ID and the sum of VALUE A and VALUE B (NULL should be zero). The result should look like:

```
ID | SCORE
----------
1  | 20
2  | 100
3  | 0
4  | 150
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
 select ID, Ifnull(valuea, 0) + IfNull(valueb, 0) as Score From MyTable
```

reference:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull

Answer (score 2):

Use [IFNULL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull)

```
select ID, IFNULL([VALUE A], 0) + IFNULL([VALUE B], 0) AS SCORE
from tbl1
```